# apc_clear_cache not working from command line in php

Tags: php, command-line-interface, apc

I have a php script which clears apc.
The script is working fine, when I opening it using browser, but when I am running that file from command line, it is not clearing cache.

I checked for apc.enable_cli setting, and that is also on (check the screenshot).
[image: Settings dump]

And here is my php-code

```
<?php

if (isset($argv[1])) {
    $key = $argv[1];

    $info = apc_cache_info("user");
    foreach ($info['cache_list'] as $obj) {
        if (strstr($obj['info'], $key)) {
            apc_delete($obj['info']);
        }
    }

} else {
    apc_clear_cache("user");
}
?>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should also post the code which clears the cache

Comment: @JakubJankowski : added the code.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PHP, but maybe it has something to do with permissions? Is there any error displayed when you run the file from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't clear APC cache from command-line, as you're not hitting the same APC segment of your webserver.

Note that `enable_cli` only allows you to use APC in a CLI environment, but creates a segment for your script, and destroy it at the end of the script. It doesn't use the same segment because it doesn't know about your webserver.

You have two options:

- call your script through FastCGI (see below)
- call the webpage with `file_get_contents()` or the like, using `http://`

If you need to access APC data, you can also read my article: https://www.dugwood.com/949904-php5-opcode-caching-and-memory-storage-with-apc-xcache-in-command-line-interface-cli-or-cron.html

Comment: I did use :

curl -s 127.0.0.1/clear_cache.php  > /dev/null &
and wrote the code in php file